# Concatenate string in a loop of shell script

Tags: string, shell, loops

I want to concatenate a suffix to a string in a loop of shell script, but the result makes me confused. The shell script is as follows:

```
for i in `cat IMAGElist.txt`
do
  echo $i
  echo ${i}_NDVI
done
```

The result is:

```
LT51240392010131BKT01
_NDVI40392010131BKT01
LT51240392010163BKT01
_NDVI40392010163BKT01
...
```

The front five chars was replaced with "_NDVI".
But the expected result should be:

```
LT51240392010131BKT01
LT51240392010131BKT01_NDVI
LT51240392010163BKT01
LT51240392010163BKT01_NDVI
...
```

I think the method for string concatenation is right if not in the loop. I don't know why this result is produced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though your file may contain Windows-style line endings (carriage return + line feed), so you should convert them to UNIX-style ones. A simple way to do this is with the tool `dos2unix`.

Don't use `for` to read lines of a text file:

```
while read -r line
do
  echo "$line"
  echo "${line}_NDVI"
done < IMAGElist.txt
```

Note that you can achieve this result more efficiently with tools designed to process text, such as awk or sed.

Comment: Thank you for your answering! I tried your approach, but the result is the same as the original.

Comment: I think the issue is probably with the line endings in your input file; I've added to my answer.